# NGINX redirect https://www.example.com to https://example.com

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx

I want to redirect my https://www.example.com to my https://example.com domain.
I managed it to make a redirect without the SSL https:// but when I add it to my domain an 400 error gets thrown.

This is my sites-available:

```
server {
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
    root /var/www/project;
    index index.html;
    server_name example.ch;
    location / { try_files $uri $uri/ =404;}





    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.ch/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.ch/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = example.ch) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    server_name example.ch;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}

server {
    server_name www.example.ch;
    return 301 $scheme://example.ch$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: So currently it should be working that 1. you access `https://example.ch` 2. you are getting redirected from `http://example.ch` to `https://example.ch` 3. you are getting redirected from `http://www.example.ch` to `https://example.ch` | but it does not work to redirect from `https://www.example.ch` to `https://example.ch` - is that all correct?

Comment: @Geilmaker correct, also the redirection fro ```www.example.com``` to ```https://example.com``` works. Just the one you told is missing

Comment: Please re-read the guidance for the tags you've used.  This is clearly a question about system configuration, not about __programming__, so is off-topic for Stack Overflow.  It _might_ be suitable for [sf]: consult the Help Centre for the site before you post.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add an ssl certificate for your www domain, if you want the https to work. Even tho you just want a redirect - but if you request the website it will do the tls handshake first and when a secure connection is established it will send the redirect to the client. So you cant send any response from `https://www.example.ch` without SSL configured for that subdomain.

Try getting a certificate and your last block should be extended somewhat like this:

```
server {
    server_name www.example.ch;
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    return 301 https://example.ch$request_uri;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.ch/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.ch/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```